# Creating a gmail template containing image and want to place text box on top of the image which can be used to provide a message. How to do that?

Tags: templates, formatting, gmail

I have an image on top of which I want to place a editable text box where anyone using the template with the image background can type in anything they want to. I am unable to place the text box on top of the image. how to do that please help?

Tried using templates, designing it in Google docs, sheet and slides but when put in Gmail the text box does not work the way I want it to.